# Error: AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed",

Tags: android, gradle, build, huawei-mobile-services

I need to remove Huawei related code from the project. I have already removed all related code from classes and files, disabled plugin and huawei repo in build(project) and build(app). When I include at least one of these dependencies, no error occurs. If I disable all dependencies, I get an error:

```
AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Android resource linking failed","sources":[{"file":"/Users/mihail/1.Projects/demo/app/src/main/res/layout/filter_checked_card.xml","position":{"startLine":1}}],"original":"/Users/mihail/1.Projects/demo/app/src/main/res/layout/filter_checked_card.xml:2: AAPT: error: resource dimen/margin_m (aka demo.ua:dimen/margin_m) not found.\n    ","tool":"AAPT"}
```

Dependencies:

```
        //Huawei SDK
//    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-core:1.3.2.301'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:push:4.0.1.300'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:4.0.0.301'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:location:4.0.2.300'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:4.0.3.300'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-crash:1.2.1.300'
//    implementation 'com.huawei.agconnect:agconnect-remoteconfig:1.3.2.301'
```

Comment: hi@Михаил Шаров, Can i confirm why you need to remove Huawei related code from your project? Is there any issue after integration?

Comment: I simplified the question. Actually, I need to separate build creation with flavor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is clear, in your filter_checked_card.xml (line 2), there is a resource `dimen/margin_m` missing.
Find out what it is, edit it or add it to dimens.xml.

Comment: @МихаилШаров what's its value?

Comment: Everything turned out to be very simple. Thanks for your reply.